# Help with algorithm

Tags: algorithms

How can I prove that is true/false
$$
f(n)+g(n)=O(f(n)\cdot g(n)) 
Where f(n),g(n) > 0
$$
I think that if $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $g(n)=n$ it can't be true but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reformulate what means the $O$ notation? In particular what means $O(1)$?

After that you should be able to prove that the result is false.

Answer (score 0):

A simple counterexample with $f(n)=g(n) = n  = O(n)$. That's if I correctly understand your question. of course.